# How to create the expansion files in android

Tags: android

Hi guys I am new to android application. recently I am developing one application.It works well and fine. But my problem is application contains the audio's and sequence images(nearly 10000 images)by the end of the project apk size is 530 MB. how to create the expansion file for that project. i want to upload the project into play store. please guys anyone help me to create how the expansion files are created for that project.
I follow this website http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html  but I can not under stand properly. please any help me

Comment: Some details here -- google Developer Console Help  -- https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en

Comment: i go through that  your suggested page but how to  my doubt is how to upload apk file(530mb)

Comment: there should be some help on how to do that on that website

Answer (score 0):

An expansion file is typically just a zip archive of the things you want to have in it. Use your favorite ZIP tool to generate it.

Comment: thanks for response how to do that can u explain some more details

Comment: No, I don't know which zip tool you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Your expansion file name format should be : [main|patch]...obb

Gather all your contents inside a folder and rename the folder as per the naming format above and with .zip as extension. 
For eg: main.1.com.your.packagename.zip.

Now you can upload this expansion file along with the apk.

Comment: but we cannot upload the apk size is more than 50 mb . i created that zip folder as u mention

Comment: Please read this information from the Android documentation page.
"Each time you upload an APK using the Google Play Developer Console, you have the option to add one or two expansion files to the APK. Each file can be up to 2GB and it can be any format you choose, but we recommend you use a compressed file to conserve bandwidth during the download."

Comment: haa i read that till now i did not upload my apk into play store @Febi Mathew